# Damage Over Time game mechanic on multiple objects (90FPS/VR Problems)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm not looking for a spoon fed solution but perhaps some insight because I have tried many different scenarios in attempt to get good performance.

I have a scenario where I would like to apply damage over time to X amount of enemies (Zombies), from a collider (Projectile).

**Current Problematic Setup**

Currently, I have a script attached to my Projectile which will `StartCoroutine` `onTriggerEnter` that will decrement the Zombies life over time. This works wonderfully, until you want to damage more than 15 or so Zombies at time.

I presume this is from some of the magic going on in all of the StartCoroutines. Here is my couroutine thats called on `OnTriggerEnter`.

```
IEnumerator DoDOT(float damageDuration, int damageCount, float damageAmount)
    {
        damagingOverTime = true;
        int currentCount = 0;
        while (currentCount < damageCount)
        {
            zombieHealth -= damageAmount;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(damageDuration);
            currentCount++;
        }
        damagingOverTime = false;
    }
```

**Possible Solution**

Now I've done a simple test (with double the amount of zombies) where I've hard coded the Damage Over Time mechanic onto the Zombies Update function. Of course when I start the scene, every single Zombie begins to take damage over time, but there are no performance issues.

I'm thinking I could have the update in my Zombie game object "watching" for a Damage Over Time flag, then my Projectile can activate that flag `OnTriggerEnter`.  The Zombie Update will than begin to apply Damage over time. Could those with more experience let me know if this is the correct approach, and if not, what is?

**Performance goal 90 FPS not 60FPS.** My current process of starting co-routines for the DOT would actually work fine in theory in a 60FPS environment because you have a lot more room for processing before it could cause a frame drop. But when you aim for 90FPS that same coroutine can not handle it because we no longer have that extra processing room. I'm trying to figure out why my Possible Solution provides more efficient results in a 90FPS environment, or what are possible solutions for more efficient results in a 90FPS environment.

PS - It's not really another zombie shooter, those terms are just examples :D

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that if you're just running the script on a bunch (15+) of zombies, it works nicely. But if the code is triggered by a collision, it starts lagging when it hits 15+ zombies?

From this I can only assume there's something wrong with your collisions... Perhaps it collides multiple times on each unit and triggers very many Coroutines? But I'm guessing would've seen that on their then probably very rapid health decrease.

Comment: Also, you might wanna change the while to a for-loop. for `(int i = 0; i < damageCount; i++) { /* Your code */ }`, easier readability.

Comment: You can add flag to prevent run this routine when it already runs. Something like `bool isDoingDOT = false;` and then at entry of your coroutine just check for that flag : `if(!isDoingDOT) { isDoingDOT = true; /*your logic*/ }`

Comment: @Fredrik Yes that is correct. Running the decrement health mechanic on a bunch of zombies (without the IEnumerator markup of course) opposed to starting a coroutine from the collider results in a big performance drop. (This is an empty scene by the way).

Comment: If you run the `StartCoroutine(DoDOT());` in the `Start()` method of the zombies, do you get performance issues?

Comment: @Fredrik No but nice one I'm excited to try this I will let you know as soon as I get back home. So are you guys thinking that there shouldn't be anything wrong with the way I'm currently going about it?

Comment: Hey just some advice, if you want a nice smooth damage over time, you should change the line to read: `zombieHealth -= (damageAmount * Time.deltaTime);` then it is a true damage over time, and if your damage amount is let's say `2.0f`, then that means it will deal `2.0f` damage every second.

Comment: Don't use any update function if it is really not needed . Instead just use FixedUpdate.

Comment: @clamchoda Well, you shouldn't get FPS drops because you're running a couple of Coroutines, especially not if it works in special conditions. Your way of doing it seems fine. Like the answer says, you could save every object you hit in a list, iterate that list and damage the zombies in it, but that wont give you a "real" DOT DPS, since every target will be taking damage at the same time. I'm guessing you want the DOT to start when the unit is hit, so that every unit won't take damage at the same time.

Comment: @Fredrik Ok thank you for your knowledge drop I appreciate all I can get. I am trying to achieve a real DOT style dps like you are describing. I do use a method of looping through the targets but this provides my AOE effect.

One thing I'm curious to is did you see my edit? My current process of starting co-routines for the DOT would actually work fine in theory in a 60FPS environment because you have a lot more room for processing before it could cause a frame drop. But when you aim for 90FPS that same coroutine can not handle it because we no longer have that extra processing power.

Comment: @clamchoda why are you running 15 coroutines, why don't you just run 1 co-routine and pass in a list of zombies in which the damage is applicable to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some debugging is needed here.
You can do something like count the numbers of times this function is called just to make sure it's not called too many times.

Another thing you can try to do is move this to the Update method of the projectile itself and keep a list of all enemies that were hit by this projectile (simply add them to the list in   OnTriggerEnter).
So instead of having many Coroutines running in the background everything is handled on a simple loop that loops through all the enemies that were hit by it.

P.s writing this on mobile sorry for any mistakes

Comment: Hey Shoker, this does work great and thank you. But I use a feature like this to apply area of affect style damage I am trying to achieve damage over time.

Comment: You can do damage over time with this. Just create a simple timer using a float and substracting Time.deltaTime . And instead of dealing damage to one enemy at a time just loop through all enemies hit. I would provide you some code but i am not home right now